# Generalised linear mixed model with Kent distribution family

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, glmm, stan

I am working with spherical directional data. I need to estimate the parameters of the Kent distribution family. The data also has uniformly distributed noise. This paper describes similar problem https://doi.org/10.1198/016214501750332974. However, in my case the location and scale parameter values also vary with one of the independent variables, X. I am thinking of using a generalised linear mixed model to estimate the relation between X and the parameters but when looked at R VGAM, BRMS, GLMM and Directional packages, I could not find any function that can solve my problem. Any suggestions on what I can do to get the relation between X and the parameters?